# Cannot call a class as a function in block plugin react component

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor, react

I'm developing a block plugin and working with the React packages for WordPress.
In my Save function I'm trying to load a slider component from the package ['react-slick'] (https://github.com/akiran/react-slick)
Here is my code.

```
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import Slider from 'react-slick';

export default function save() {
    var settings = {
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      };

    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps.save() }>
            <Slider {...settings} >
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </Slider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

When I run this I get the following error ,

> TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
> at _classCallCheck (inner-slider.js:40:93)
> at InnerSlider (inner-slider.js:70:1)

So at some point the Slider component doesn't like being returned or called within the save() function. I'm coming from a PHP background and am just starting with React so could anyone point out what exactly is going wrong, perhaps some concept to do with React.

Comment: The save function is for generating HTML to save into the database. It cannot save an interactive react component. You should save the HTML of the content that you need and then load a separate script on the front end that turns the HTML into a slider on page load.

Comment: Did you find any solution? If yes then please add here.